# How to use loops for macro function calls in sas

Tags: loops, macros, sas

I am using the following statements for function calls in sas

```
%loopit(26062015,bbbbbbINFY,FUTSTK,30Jul2015);
%loopit(26062015,bbbbbbSBIN,FUTSTK,30Jul2015);
%loopit(26062015,bbbbbbbTCS,FUTSTK,30Jul2015);
```

where i have already have defined the loopit macro previously in the code. As it can be seen, in the function calls, only one parameter changes while the rest are same. I wanted to if there are any loop structures (e.g. Arrays) I can use to make it more useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a list of parameters to loop through and then call `%loopit` on each of them:

```
%let param_list = bbbbbbINFY bbbbbbSBIN bbbbbbbTCS;

%macro loop_them;

    %do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&param_list.));
    %let this_param = %scan(&param_list., &i.);

        %loopit(26062015,&this_param.,FUTSTK,30Jul2015);

    %end;

%mend loop_them;

%loop_them;
```

Comment: Much better would be to make `param_list` a parameter for `%loop_them`.

Comment: And make &i and &this_param %local to the macro, to avoid collisions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `call execute` function. For example if you have a sequential count base parameter you are passing then you can use the following code:

```
Data _NULL_;
count = 0;
for i=0 to 10;
call execute ( ‘%loopit(count)’ );
end;
run;
```

I am not entirely sure about the syntax used above. Google for more clarity. I have used `call execute` in the same manner earlier.